# Make new int[] array or use loop to set every index to 0? Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm making a yahtzee game in java, and I have a variable called frequencyCount which is an array keeping track of how many die there is of each one. I reset this array after each roll with a for loop setting each index to 0.

```
for(int i = 0; i < frequencyCount.length; i++) {
    frequencyCount[i] = 0;
}
```

But is there any problem with just creating a new array each time like this:

```
frequencyCount = new int[6];
```

The reset method will be called 45 times per player per game.

Which way is best? Is it a problem to keep creating new arrays, or doesn't it matter since this is a small game?

Comment: A modern Java VM can create millions of arrays without you even noticing. 45 and 6 are tiny tiny numbers for a computer. 99.99999% of the time spent in your program will consist in doing nothing, and wait for the user interactions. As long as no other object has a reference to the old array, resetting it or creating a new one won't change anything.

Comment: Note that you can also use `Arrays.fill(frequencyCount, 0);` (which just saves you from writing the loop yourself).

Comment: @JBNizet It can create millions of *small* arrays, large (thousands, millions of elements) arrays are a different matter. And many important programs don't spend the majority (let alone 99.99999%) of their time waiting for user input. Even those who do may have *latency* constraints that make optimizations worthwhile. Not to condone premature optimization, but I prefer to dismiss these concerns for *right* reasons.

Comment: I would recommend dispensing with using arrays entirely. Use the `ArrayList` implementation of the `List` interface - it has a very convenient `clear()` method.

Comment: @delnan: we're talking about 45 creations of arrays of length 6 here, for a Yathzee program. The same optimization rules don't apply for such a program and a low-latency high-volume trading application. My point is to make the OP realize that a computer is fast. Much faster than he can imagine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In practice you will not see any difference, you shouldn't worry too much about performance in cases like this. Focus on keeping your code clean and readable, and I believe method no. 2 is more concise.

Answer (score 1):

both ways are almost identical, new int[] also uses for loop to make all of them zero (optimized) but will throw the old array and make the GC work, so both ways almost identical

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dima; both methods produce the same result. I would say to use the second because it requires fewer lines of code. There is no need to create new arrays when one will suffice.